# A basic question on $\pi$-system and borel sigma algebra

Tags: probability-theory

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Is it true that there exist a $\pi$ system such that it generates the borel sigma algebra $B(X)$. If not can we find any sufficient condition on $(X,d)$ so that it holds.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $B(X)$ is itself such a $\pi$-system. Less trivially, the collection of open sets is such a $\pi$-system, as is the collection of closed sets. If $X$ is separable, then another example is the collection of all finite intersections of open balls $B(x,r)$, $x\in X$, $r>0$.

Comment: Regarding the last line, this implies that any open set in $X$ can be written as a "counable" union of such finite intersection of open balls. This does not look true.

Comment: Without finite intersection it would still generate the $\sigma$-algebra but would not necessarily be a $\pi$-system.

Comment: you are correct.